# Power Automate and Direct Query in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, power-automate, directquery

Can I use Power Automate for Direct Query data refresh in Power BI?

Will it be faster than the Enterprise Gateway Direct Query Connection?

Comment: Can you outline how you would use Power Automate in such away? I don't think you can use it as a gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For direct query you don't need to have any power automate flow to refresh the data,
if your dataset is connected to the gateway then it will automatically get the latest data whenever the user interact with the report.

Data refresh required if you have import mode

FYI, even if you use power automate the refresh the data it happens via gateway itself, so pls go ahead with the regular process.